# Rails: Authenticate before routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### The What.

I'm trying to implement <strike>token based</strike> Basic authentication on my Rails API. It works fine for existing routes, but here's the catch:

When an unauthenticated user visits a route that does NOT exist, it displays the `404 - Not found` page, and not the `401 - Unauthorized`. How do I get Rails to check authentication ***before*** validating the routes?

Here's my `application_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController
  # Main controller inherited by all API controllers

  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # Enforce site-wide authentication
  before_action :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
  end

  def authenticate_token
    # Can we find a user with the authentication token used?
    authenticate_with_http_basic do |u, p|
      # Only search active, private keys
      @api_key = ApiKey.active.find_by(api_key: u, is_secret: true)
      @user = @api_key.user if @api_key

      return @api_key
    end
  end

  def render_unauthorized
    # Displays the Unauthorized message
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate({ 
      error: { 
        type: "unauthorized",
        message: "This page cannot be accessed without a valid API key."
        } 
      }), status: 401
  end
end
```

### The Why

Think of it this way: someone stops you at the office to ask for directions. Do you ask them to present some ID first or do you just show them the way?

If it were a public office, I'd just show them the way .. but if we were in the restricted Special Projects division at the CIA, I don't care where you're going (<strike>even</strike> *especially* if you tell me you're looking for Office 404, which I know doesn't exist): I want to see some ID first.

### Edit: Using Basic Auth

I originally mentioned Token based authentication, but it's actually Basic Auth (with "username" = "token").

Comment: i don't think that this is possible on the controller level. what's wrong with a 404?

Comment: @phoet added it to the question.

Comment: you might especially want to see ID if someone turns up looking for an office that doesn't exist. That's a sure sign that they probably shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the built-in rails authentication you can't achieve what you want for the very reason @rich-peck explained. Rails first evaluate your routes, then passes the request for the controller.

You have two options. First, do exactly what the Stripe guys are doing. Delegate the authentication to the web server in front of your app server (nginx in their case).

```
$ curl -I https://api.stripe.com/this/route/doesnt/exist
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2014 21:21:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Stripe"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Stripe-Version: 2014-08-04
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains
```

Or, if you want/need to keep it in ruby-land, you can use a rack middleware which will authenticate before rails loads your routes. You can try https://github.com/iain/rack-token_auth

```
$ bin/rake middleware
...snip a bunch of middleware...
use Rack::TokenAuth
run Dummy::App::Application.routes
```

**Update:** Using HTTP Basic Authentication

In that case, you don't need another library at all, because rack has built-in support for http basic auth through the `Rack::Auth::Basic` middleware, e.g.

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
  username == "bob" && password == "secret"
end
```

**Update:** Can I apply the authentication to the `API` namespace?

It depends. Because the rack middleware runs before rails loads your routes, controllers, etc. it has no knowledge of your namespaces. Nonetheless, if your namespaced controllers are also namespaced at the URL level, e.g. all under `/api`, you can check `request.path` to whether apply the authentication.

You can create a new rack middlware to *decorate* `Rack::Auth::Basic` with this behaviour, e.g.

```
class MyAPIAuth < Rack::Auth::Basic
  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if request.path =~ /\A\/api\/?/
      super
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end

# change your configuration to use your middleware
config.middleware.use MyAPIAuth do |username, password|
  username == "bob" && password == "secret"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @wicz, I like the idea of using middleware for the API. I'll give it a quick shot to see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually Basic Auth and not Token based authentication (see edit). Do you have any suggestions for a rack-basic auth library?

Comment: Hello @Samantha, I've updated the answer with a solution using HTTP Basic Authentication. HTH.

Comment: thanks so much! That looks like exactly what I needed - Is it at all possible to apply this configuration just to the `API` namespace?

Comment: Hi @Samantha, updated my answer again regarding your previous comment. Cheers.

Comment: Awesomelicious! Thanks so much Vinicius - bounty coming up in 3 hours :)

Comment: Just curious.  Is the @app defined anywhere for the `@app.call(env)`?

Comment: I found it.  Rack::Auth::AbstractHandler https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/auth/abstract/handler.rb#L12

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to append a catch-all route at the end of your routes.rb:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # Standard routes
  # ...

  # Catch-all
  get '*other', to: 'dummy#show'
end
```

Then have a dummy controller just render `404 - Not Found` in show action. Should anyone visit a non-existing route it will be handled by dummy, which will perform authentication first in a before filter and if it fails `401 - Unauthorized` is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting past the idea of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

[image]

When you send a request to Rails, the routing mechanism is meant to take the requested URL & send you to a particular area (`controller`). The authentication happens inside that controller - allowing you handle routed traffic in a modular way

I think the problem you have is authenticating before you send the user to the respective controller goes against MVC principles - whereby your authentication (pinging the database) will have to happen *before* you get to the controller / model

---

**Authentication**

Have you checked out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast)?

[image]

It shows how to use token authentication in your controller - allowing you to secure your API

Comment: Thanks Rich. I actually used that article as a reference when building my controller. So your answer is: it's bad and shouldn't be done? What prompted the question is that I noticed Stripe displays the authentication dialog on their API, no matter [where you land](https://api.stripe.com/this/route/doesnt/exist).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your on Rails 3.X.X just as I was and was receiving the same error (they used Rails 4 for the Code School lesson).  Here's what you have to change:

before_action :authenticate
***must be changed to***
before_filter :authenticate

User.find_by(auth_token: token)
***must be changed to***
User.find_by_auth_token(token)

Comment: Nope, the problem has nothing to do with methods naming, also, the question is tagged with #ruby-on-rails-4.

Comment: Rails 4.1.4 - 2.1.2p95; I don't think it's got to do with naming, like @wicz said, and `before_action` = `before_filter`